# Which modal plugin jQuery DataTables uses

Tags: jquery, datatables

Which plugin does jQuery DataTables use for its modal dialogs?

The demo [here](http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/server-side-processing.html) has it if you click "New".